# How to use a small balance in Google Play store

Tags: google-play-store

I need to change the country of my Google account. However, since there is less than a Euro on my balance I cannot to do so unless I make my Google balance zero.
I cannot split a payment between my credit card and the Google balance. I also cannot add a custom amount to my balance to buy a service.
Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: Just be aware that you can only change the country once a year (unless that policy has changed recently).  So, the question is, WHY do you want to change the country?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Good point! I cannot use the food delivery apps in the current country. However, you are right if someone has to move to another place sooner than one year it is going to be problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to get your balance directly to zero, but do you know that Amazon allows to buy Google vouchers at any value you want?

You can simply enter the amount of euro and cent so if you want to buy something you could load the missing amount and then buy it. Afterwards the balance would be zero.